# jQuery: Is event object implicitly passed during event handling?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following function which binds a series of event handlers to the DOM:

```
  $( document ).on({
    "mousewheel": scrollHandler,
    "DOMMouseScroll": ("onmousewheel" in document) ? null : scrollHandler, // Firefox
    "mousedown": function( e ) {
      if( e.button === 1 ) {
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
      }
    }
  });

  $( window ).on( "resize", function() { scrollToStep( step ); } ); // Re-centers the screen
```

Each event handler links to scrollHandler, but none of them pass scrollHandler the event object. And yet, in the function definition of scrollHandler, the function has full access to the event object:

```
function scrollHandler( e ) {
  var scrollDelta = e.originalEvent.wheelDelta || -e.originalEvent.detail,
      dir = scrollDelta / ( Math.abs( scrollDelta ) );

  e.preventDefault();
  $( window ).scrollTop( 0 ).scrollLeft( 0 );
  scrollSteps( -dir * STEP_SIZE );
}
```

How is this possible? Where is the argument `e` coming from in scrollHandler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're confused on what's happening here. `"mousedown"` and `"mousewheel"` are actually doing the same thing. The functions are not being called in the `on` call. They're just telling jQuery, "Hey, next time this event happens call this function and pass the current event". It doesn't matter if it's defined inline (like `"mousedown"`) or defined somewhere (like `"mousewheel"`) else (as long as they're within the same scope).

You'll probably want to google for articles on "callbacks in javascript" if this is still not making sense.